# Filter out tables from Commit changes GUI in Red Gate SQL Source Control

Tags: sql, sql-server, redgate

When committing SQL changes with Red Gate SQL Source Control, the GUI will show each table that has been modified along with a view of the actual data in a little window pane at the bottom of the "Commit Changes" tab.

The problem I'm running into is that the default table that gets pre-selected and viewed through this tab is massive and Red Gate throws me a Out-Of-Memory error each time.

Is there a way to not have certain tables show up at all in the Commit changes tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use filters to exclude the object.

In SSMS in the Object Explorer, right-click a database, folder, or object, then select Other SQL Source Control Tasks and click Edit Filter Rules.

That will stop it getting shown on the commit changes grid.  Hope that helps.

Full details in the [docs](http://documentation.red-gate.com/display/SOC3/Using+filters+to+exclude+objects)